# Partition of complete boolean algebra induces partition on elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Given a complete boolean algebra B, and two partitions W and T of B, why is it true that W induces a partition on every element of T? (And is this true more generally - does W induce a partition on every  non zero element of B?)

This is motivated by trying to understand the solution given here : [If $B$ is an infinite complete Boolean algebra, then its saturation is a regular uncountable cardinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107150/if-b-is-an-infinite-complete-boolean-algebra-then-its-saturation-is-a-regular?rq=1) to theorem 7.15 in Jech's Set Theory.

Comment: If $t\in T$, $\{w\land t:w\in W\text{ and }w\land t\ne 0_B\}$ is the partition of $t$ induced by $W$.

Comment: That was my first thought, but why is that set a subset of W? For instance the product of w and w∧t is non-zero?

Comment: It almost certainly isn’t a subset of $W$: the only time that it’s a subset of $W$ is when $t$ happens to be the join of some members of $W$. The claim isn’t that each member of $T$ can be partitioned into members of $W$; it’s simply that there each $t\in T$ has a partition naturally generated by $W$, and the partition that’s meant is the one that I described.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. So this works for any non-zero element of B. Is there a way I can upvote your comment?

Comment: Yes, it works fine for any non-zero element of $B$. Don’t worry about upvoting; I’m happy enough that you got it sorted out!

Comment: I'm sure I'm being really daft, but why can we pull the t term out of the set when taking the supremum? (Of course it is obvious if we imagine the Boolean algebra to be an algebra of sets. But I cant seem to see why it is justified in the general case)

Comment: Complete Boolean algebras satisfy the infinite distributive laws; the one that's needed here is proved in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/107927/12042).

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: You're very welcome.